# Text editor which can convert speech to text and vice-versa

Tags: python, windows, text-editor

I am thinking of implementing a text editor for my academic project which can convert speech to text and also speak the written text.

Is it possible to code it in Python? Or is it possible at all? If possible, how?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion hering. Its my first question in here and I really needed help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is very much possible. If you are a beginner, I recommend you use python to do this. You can use PyQt for your GUI, [pyttsx](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyttsx) and [SpeechRecognition](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/) for the speech engine (offline). Do the following to install them:

```
 pip install SpeechRecognition
 pip install pyttsx
```

Here's some code to get you started on the speech recognition in python

```
import speech_recognition
import pyttsx

speech_engine = pyttsx.init('sapi5') # see http://pyttsx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/engine.html#pyttsx.init
speech_engine.setProperty('rate', 150)

def speak(text):
    speech_engine.say(text)
    speech_engine.runAndWait()

recognizer = speech_recognition.Recognizer()

def listen():
    with speech_recognition.Microphone() as source:
        recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        audio = recognizer.listen(source)

    try:
        return recognizer.recognize_sphinx(audio)
        # or: return recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
    except speech_recognition.UnknownValueError:
        print("Could not understand audio")
    except speech_recognition.RequestError as e:
        print("Recog Error; {0}".format(e))

    return ""

speak("Say something!")
speak("I heard you say " + listen())
```

Comment: Let me know if you need anymore help. If my answer helped you, please accept the answer. Thanks!